# Can I say "It are ..."?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentences:

> The only exceptions are requirements and risk-based approaches,
>   which are not considered in this paper since it really depends
>   on the human experts. Apart from it, techniques, which are dealing
>   with GUI/WEB application testing, and model-based techniques are also
>   excluded from this research since it are usually out of unit testing
>   scope, or require some specific resources or tools.

Grammarly says that I have to write **is** instead of **are** in the second sentence (look at the pic. below). Will it be a correct sentence if I follow the Grammarly recommendations? Or should I write here **they are** due to the plural?

Why can't I leave **it are**? It seems logical since **techniques** is a plural noun...

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the initial "it" refers to in your sentence? This is hard to answer otherwise, but it seems that the plural "techniques" would require the second "it" to become "they." I suspect that you (and Grammarly, fwiw) would have an easier time seeing this if you untangled this sentence slightly, or perhaps made it two sentences. The current construction is slightly unclear. (E.g., do you mean "techniques that deal with GUI/WEB..." etc.)

Comment: ... since *they* are usually ...

Comment: What the initial "it" is referring to is unclear.

Comment: IMO the whole paragraph needs reviewing. It begins by saying what the "only exceptions" are, but goes on to mention more exclusions. I suggest that you start by saying that certain things have been excluded, and then list what they are. If they need some explanation, you can separate them with bullet points, or make each one a small paragraph describing what it is and why it is excluded.

Comment: I do not understand this question. At all. But as a general rule, if you are using Grammarly, you are always wrong. Always. No exceptions.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to add the context. Initial _it_ refers to the _exceptions_ from the previous sentence. My question is about the second _it_. Should there be _are_ or _is_? As far as I got, It should be _they_ _are_. Thank you all guys for your answers and comments!

Comment: All fine points of criticism, including the downvote. Just not very welcoming to a new contributor. So: hi and welcome to English.SE @MichaelAbyzov.

Comment: I suspect that you're trying to translate the Russian word *э́то* (*éto*) as *it*. However, the English word *it* is always singular; it is never used as a plural. For a singular, use *it is*, and for a plural, use *they are*. We never say *it are*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "are" in your sentence seems to refer to the plural "techniques" and so it seems that the "it" that precedes it should become a "they," despite Grammarly's opinion.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I’ve edited to remove a reference to the comments section. Stack Exchange answers should be self-contained (not an ongoing dialogue with the OP). Feel free to edit further if you wish.